# SSH туннель, авторизация ключом

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Подключаюсь к серверу используя vscode remote, через ssh.
На сервере два пользователя root и sites.

Мой конфиг на компе выглядит так:

`[PC] .config`

```
Host Connect_Tunel
  HostName localhost
  Port 22
  User sites
  IdentityFile "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\keys\\common_pc_rsa"
  ProxyJump root@###.###.###.###
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p root@###.###.###.###
```

Все подключается, хорошо, но спрашивает пароль.
Подозреваю что `IdentityFile` должен быть `/root/.ssh/common_root_rsa`, a у sites надо добавить `authorized_keys` с публичным ключом внутри. Однако это не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать.

**UPD:**

Добавил у пользователя sites авторизованный ключ root, теперь пароль от sites не требует

`[PC] .config`

```
Host Connect_Tunel
  HostName localhost
  Port 22
  User sites
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/localhost_root_rsa
  ProxyJump root@###.###.###.###
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p root@###.###.###.###
```

Но для root пароль просит, пробовал сделать, как посоветовал [@eri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1457093/208171), ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityFile тут относится к localhost. Что-то вроде чтоб авторизоваться на прокси

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -i "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\keys\\common_pc_rsa"  root@###.###.###.###
```

Comment: Вновь вернулся к этому вопросу, для root пароль не будет запрашивать если сертификат будет тут -> C:\Users\user\.ssh и с именем id_rsa. Посмотрев по логам этот путь и название, ssh просматривает по умолчанию и если не находит просит пароль, но почему игнорируется флаг -i так и не понял, так же как и -o "IdentityFile=..."

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать таким образом:

```
# [PC].config

Host Connect
  HostName ###.###.###.###
  User root
  Port 22
  IdentityFile "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\keys\\common_pc_rsa"
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -i "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\keys\\common_pc_rsa" root@###.###.###.###

Host Connect_Tunel
  HostName localhost
  User sites
  Port 22
  IdentityFile "C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\keys\\common_pc_rsa"
  ProxyJump Connect
```

**P.S.**
Не понимаю правда зачем трижды подключать ключ и по идее у `Connect_Tunel` должно быть `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/localhost_root_rsa`...